# Flickering horizontal scrollbar in Aptana 3.6

Tags: eclipse-plugin, aptana

I have installed Aptana studio for Eclipse.

Now, once I open any file and type a button - horizontal bar shows in and then disappears. Fast typing results in the annoying flickering which makes impossible to work with Aptana.

Is it possible to solve this somehow or make horizontal scrollbar always stay visible (like for example in Android Development Kit)?

Answer (score 2):

Only way I have seen to remove this is removing word wrap at
Preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Editors

You have to restart aptana in order to implement the word wrap.

It's one of the maaaaaaany bugs that the new version has.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I've tried it already with no result. For now I have just organized my workspace the way that scrollbar is always visible. Waiting for 3.6.1, will hope they fix it.